# That's the guy I drove here

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

A taxi driver has just dropped a customer off at a building. Before the taxi driver drives off, the police arrives.

Taxi driver - *Who are you looking for?*

Police officer - *His name is James Davis.*

Taxi driver - *Oh my God, **that's the guy I drove here**. He just went inside.*

Question: Is the highlighted part natural?

Comment: Completely natural. Why wouldn't it be?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is normal.

E.g.

*I drove John to the railway station.*

*My father drove me here in his new Ferrari.*

We know that the job of a taxi-driver is to drive people (to) places.

Answer (score -1):

In response to your yes or no question, and as a matter of opinion, I would say yes, on the following basis.

Using the only reasonable alternative pronoun in that line would make it, "Oh my God, *he's* the guy I drove here. He just went inside." There's a certain degree of redundancy, given the cop has already said a typically masculine name and used a masculine pronoun, and because however unconsciously he might know it, the taxi driver already has the sentence "*He* just went inside" queued up next. Changing *that* final sentence to "That just went inside." doesn't work on its own. In this role with personal pronouns, *that* only works as a modifier to specify a individual or to extend and connect additional modifiers to a clear and original subject: "He's the guy I drove over here that just went inside 10 minutes ago." works, but it also implies that there's another guy the taxi driver just drove over here who went inside 5 minutes ago. Going back to the direct substitution on your original, "That just went inside 10 minutes ago.", wouldn't work because James Davis is a person, not a 'that'. So the reason *that* works for "that's the guy I just drove here" works and rings naturally because the taxi driver and a cop both know that a taxi driver drives lots of guys. James Davis just happens to be the guy that the taxi driver just drove over here.

Additionally, the inference one might make from "*he's* the guy I drove here" could be a certain degree of familiarity or intimacy on the part of the taxi driver -- i.e.: "Mick Jagger? He's the guy I drove here [and I already knew who he was and you do too because he's Mick Jagger]." vs. "James Davis? That's the guy I drove here [whose name I happened to catch and who I would have forgotten by tonight except now you're asking about him]." That's a more subtle distinction, and similarly "he's the guy I drove" could work for James Davis as it might suggest a degree of shock/surprise at the coincidence more readily, but frankly, in the context of the exchange and participants, your original "that's the guy..." rings more true.